# Sorting in golang

Tags: sorting, go

I am creating a leave application using go lang.My struct is as follows

```
Leave struct {
        Leaveid     int
        Name        string
        EmployeeId  string
        Applieddate time.Time
        Leavestatus string
    }
```

The Leave status varies between Processing ,Approved ,Denied, HRApproved, HrDenied, HrProcessing. 
By general the leave sort order must be based on applied date.
I must be able to show the Processing and HRProcessing first  and other status types later.

I want something like this

```
        [
          {
            "Leaveid": 4,
            "Name": "rajesh",
            "EmployeeId": "rajesh",
            "Applieddate": "2016-12-02T08:59:02.870882+08:00",
            "Leavestatus": "HRProcessing"
          },
          {
            "Leaveid": 1,
            "Name": "rajesh",
            "EmployeeId": "rajesh",
            "Applieddate": "2016-12-02T07:30:01.679636+08:00",
            "Leavestatus": "Processing"
          },
{
            "Leaveid": 3,
            "Name": "rajesh",
            "EmployeeId": "rajesh",
            "Applieddate": "2016-12-02T07:00:02.870882+08:00",
            "Leavestatus": "HRProcessing"
          },
         {
            "Leaveid": 5,
            "Name": "rajesh",
            "EmployeeId": "rajesh",
            "Applieddate": "2016-12-02T10:00:11.139189+08:00",
            "Leavestatus": "Approved"
          },
          {
            "Leaveid": 2,
            "Name": "rajesh",
            "EmployeeId": "rajesh",
            "Applieddate": "2016-12-02T07:58:41.837666+08:00",
            "Leavestatus": "HRApproved"
          },

        ]
```

> Update:This is what i have done using sort package

```
func (sortleave leaveDetails) Len() int {
    return len(sortleave)
}
func (sortleave leaveDetails) Less(i, j int) bool {
    if sortleave[i].Applieddate.After(sortleave[j].Applieddate) {
        return true
    }
    if sortleave[i].Applieddate.Before(sortleave[j].Applieddate) {
        return false
    }
    return sortleave[i].Leavestatus > sortleave[j].Leavestatus
}
func (sortleave leaveDetails) Swap(i, j int) {
    sortleave[i], sortleave[j] = sortleave[j], sortleave[i]
}
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "Leaveid": 2,
    "Name": "rajesh",
    "EmployeeId": "rajesh",
    "Applieddate": "2016-12-02T08:59:45.139189+08:00",
    "Leavestatus": "HRProcessing"
  },
  {
    "Leaveid": 4,
    "Name": "rajesh",
    "EmployeeId": "rajesh",
    "Applieddate": "2016-12-02T08:59:02.870882+08:00",
    "Leavestatus": "HRApproved"
  },
  {
    "Leaveid": 3,
    "Name": "rajesh",
    "EmployeeId": "rajesh",
    "Applieddate": "2016-12-02T08:58:41.837666+08:00",
    "Leavestatus": "Processing"
  },
  {
    "Leaveid": 1,
    "Name": "rajesh",
    "EmployeeId": "rajesh",
    "Applieddate": "2016-12-01T18:10:01.679636+08:00",
    "Leavestatus": "Processing"
  }
]
```

Here Processing goes down and HRApproved goes up.But this is  not what i wanted.Please help me  to solve this problem.Thanks

Comment: What have you tried, what part are you stuck on? have you looked at the examples in the sort std library package ?

Comment: I have tried the sort package to do this but the results are not what i expected.I will update what i did.Please correct me if i m wrong.Thanks...

Comment: Which is the sorting you're looking for?

Comment: Your output is properly sorted by Applieddate. So: What's wrong?

Comment: As you can see the HRApproved is before the processing .What i need is Processing and HRProccessing must come first but sorted by applied date and then all other the leave states must come after these but sorted by applied date between them.Appreciate any help.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sort by Leavestatus first,then applieddate, but leavestatus is a set of enums rather than being alpha sorted, so you'll want to catogorize the status, see if they're they same if so, sort by date, otherwise sort by the status. something like

```
func (d leaveDetails) Less(i, j int) bool {
    status := func(l Leave) int {
        if l.Leavestatus == "Processing" || l.Leavestatus == "HRProcessing" {
            return 1
        }
        return 2
    }
    a := status(d[i])
    b := status(d[j])
    if a == b {
        return d[i].Applieddate.After(d[j].Applieddate)
    }
    return a<b
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining `Leavestatus` as a `string` seems pretty inefficient since you'd need to do string comparison and copying the struct involves copying the `Leavestatus` even though it's just a "enum"-like type. This also makes it easier to introduce typo-based bugs since compiler can't check if you typed strings right.

I would make a int based type for `Leavestatus`, e.g. `LeaveStatus`

```
type LeaveStatus int

const (
    _ = iota
    Processing
    HRProcessing
    HRApproved
)
```

Then you can have `String()` method on the type:

```
func (s LeaveStatus) String() string {
    switch(s) {
        case Processing:
            return "Processing"
        case HRProcessing:
            return "HRProcessing"
        case Approved:
            return "Approved"
        default:
            panic("O_O")
    }
}
```

Since `LeaveStatus` is a number-based type now, you can just compare the field using `<` and `>` operators in your `Less()` implementation.